# Virtual online Minyan for daily Kaddish?

Tags: kaddish, minyan

I haven't been observant in almost 20 years, but recent events make me yearn to say Kaddish for those who died on October 7th, and for those IDF soldiers that are dying now. For various reasons, and in-person Minyan is currently impossible for me. Are there any virtual Minyans for saying Kaddish?  I would strongly prefer an orthodox-led Minyan, but a conservative one will do as well.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Damin and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @Damin By all means if you feel that saying Kaddish is a good thing to do then go for it, and having that connection to a minyan may help you, but I'd also suggest to simply sincerely speak to God in your own words wherever you are to ask him to protect the IDF, return the captives, heal the injured, elevate the souls of those who have died and to grant us peace.  You always have a direct connection to Him, wherever and whenever you want, and your sincere prayers will have an effect, irrespective of whether you are observant or not.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for coming here.

I'm looking at the [calendar of DC's Ohev Sholom Synagogue](https://www.ohevdc.org/calendar); it looks like they assemble a traditional minyan in-person, but also (on weekdays) keep a Zoom camera on for others to pray along. I'd suggest you contact them.

There's certainly been a lot of loss and mourning going on, and your instinct to react with prayer is a welcome one. Still, Kaddish is usually said by those mourning an immediate relative, or those appointed by mourners to do so. But I'd suggest that you contact Ohev's rabbi and ask him how he feels about you saying Kaddish.

(I don't know if the Zoom session mutes the remote attendees' microphones; or if you want to say Kaddish along with them and keep your mic muted, I can't see any harm in it, and it sounds like it might help you.)

Whether you do or don't say kaddish, just planning to pray along with a minyan (even if you're on Zoom and they're in-person) sounds like a significant step for you and a way of connecting with your faith and your people at this difficult time; maybe give that a try?

Good luck, and may we hear better news.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently Conservative ones going on as a cultural hangover from the pandemic.  You will not find an Orthodox one because they do not consider such a concept to be legitimate.  I hope you understand if I do not provide a zoom link and password to a stranger in a public posting.  If you are serious about this, contact a Conservative rabbi, ideally in your area, and work through them.  Good luck and I hope it is meaningful.

Comment: There probably still are a very few orthodox minyanim that are still broadcasting on zoom, but it is certainly way way way fewer than non orthodox ones.

Comment: while most Orthodox minyanim would not allow the ten people for the quorum to be assembled via Zoom, once there is an in-person quorum, reciting or answering Kaddish by Zoom, telephone, etc. is much less clear and may be allowed